# remove scaffold and other unplaced sequence before mapping?

Tags: bioinformatics

I downloaded reference genomes from Ensembl (fasta format). But there are lots of sequences with name "dna:scaffold": 
https://github.com/CTLife/TEMP/tree/master/RefGenomes

Such as `Mouse_GRCm38 (mm10)`, except `chromosome 1-19, Mt, X and Y`; others should be removed before mapping ?

Such as `Human_GRCh38.p5 (hg38)`, https://github.com/CTLife/TEMP/blob/master/RefGenomes/Human_GRCh38.p5.txt, there are 516 sequences. In addition to `chromosome 1-22, Mt, X and Y`; others (such as `CHR_HG2241_PATCH` and `KI270728.1`) should be removed before mapping ?

Comment: see [here](https://sequencing.qcfail.com/articles/genomic-sequence-not-in-the-genome-assembly-creates-mapping-artefacts) for a nice explanation of why you might not want to remove those extra sequences until after mapping

Comment: Thank you. I know that why I can't remove those extra sequences for mapping. But  they should be removed before peak calling.